# How do I mock this protected method and return an Object using Jmockit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, jmockit

I have the following method in class DummyClass :

```
protected Response prepareResponse(String Id, BigInteger version, String Reason, boolean isSuccessful,
        String errorCode, String errorMessage)
```

Inside the method, I am setting all the parameters in the arguments to the Response and returning it. But I wonder how to mock the method using Jmockit.

So far, I used the following approach :

```
      new MockUp<DummyClass>() {
          @Mock protected Response prepareResponse(String Id, BigInteger version, String Reason, boolean isSuccessful,
                    String errorCode, String errorMessage){
                        // I am not sure what to return here. I have to set the fields and return the response object. But I am not sure how to do it.

          }
    };
```

I am stuck until here. Please let me know.

Thanks,
Gautham

Comment: What exactly is holding you back? You should just be able to set the fields on Response and return it, right? Well, create a new Response and then set the fields and return it. So what is the issue?

Comment: Ok, I get this one. Thanks.

Comment: I realize my last comment may have seemed a little snarky; my apologies. The important thing to remember is that you are mocking things here. You don't *have* to do anything besides return a Response; often, though, assertions are included in `MockUp` code to ensure that it's being called with the right parameters etc. In this case you are choosing not to mock the Response object (which is fine for simple beans etc); so you just have to make one and return it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know MockUp worked as a constructor. I was assuming it would invoke an inaccessible method like the one provided by Deencapsulation Utils. I am still new to this mocking tool. But thanks, you have helped me learn quite a bit about this.

Comment: It's not exactly a constructor ... more of a dynamic redefinition of your class. By calling the `new MockUp<DummyClass>()` constructor, you are saying that henceforth, `prepareResponse()` will do what you define it as here, and not what the code originally said. You still need to make a `new DummyClass()` or some other means of obtaining a `DummyClass` in order to *use* it. Have you seen [the documentation for this feature](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html)? It explains it all in detail.

Comment: Ok, so it is like telling a method inside a class what it should return by instantiating a anonymous inner type class.